# Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' property '$1' during up-to-date check.

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I am not able to run my react native project it shows following error

```
    Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
    Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\ALL\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.infer.annotation\infer-annotation\0.11.2\f514ff4ca022a579d9cf7524846988b646ae4491\infer-annotation-0.11.2.jar'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing node_modules folder and re-running npm install

OR

Run the file after deleting

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: removing the modules_2 from cache worked, Thanks for the idea